# SQLite3's dynamic typing

Tags: database, sqlite, dynamic-typing

SQLite3 uses dynamic typing rather than static typing, in contrast to other flavors of SQL.  The [SQLite website](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) reads:

> Most SQL database engines (every SQL database engine other than SQLite, as far as we know) uses static, rigid typing. With static typing, the datatype of a value is determined by its container - the particular column in which the value is stored.
>
> SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container.

It seems to me that this is exactly what you *don't* want, as it lets you store, for example, strings in integer columns.

The page continues:

> ...the dynamic typing in SQLite allows it to do things which are not possible in traditional rigidly typed databases.

I have two questions:

1. The use case question:  What are some examples where SQLite3's dynamic typing is beneficial?
2. The historical/design question:  What was the motivation for implementing SQLite with dynamic typing?

Comment: My observation is that sqlite3 is more dependent on the software interfacing it being smarter, for example counting on it to not store integers in string columns, rather than providing structure on its own.

Comment: This is the type of discussion question that's often better as Community Wiki, but is, in general, a poor question for SO's format.  Try asking *one* question per.. question, and it's preferable to be specific rather than open-ended. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is called [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) in SQLite.

According to the SQLite website, they have done this "in order to maximize compatibility between SQLite and other database engines." (see the above link)

> SQLite supports the concept of "type affinity" on columns. The type affinity of a column is the recommended type for data stored in that column. The important idea here is that the type is recommended, not required. Any column can still store any type of data. It is just that some columns, given the choice, will prefer to use one storage class over another. The preferred storage class for a column is called its "affinity".

My understanding is that SQLite is exactly what it's named for - a very lightweight, minimalistic database engine. The overhead associated with strong typing is probably beyond the scope of the project, and best left to the application that uses SQLite.

But again, according to their website, they've done this to maximize compatibility with other DB engines.

Comment: > This is called type affinity in SQLite.

"Type affinity" is a specific aspect of sqlite's dynamic typing---columns have a recommended type, but the actual values are free to be of other types.

> According to the SQLite website, they have done this "in order to maximize compatibility between SQLite and other database engines."

Yes, they do say that, but it is regarding the type affinity, not the dynamic typing in general.

Comment: Regarding the "overhead associated with strong typing":  Assuming you in fact mean "static typing":  I imagine that using static typing would allow for _more_ efficient implementation than dynamic typing.  For instance, storage could be more compact, and many type checks could be avoided when querying.

Comment: I apologize for the formatting of the earlier comments:  I thought markdown was allowed.  I'm new here.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at, say, Firefox's "about:config" page, I believe these settings are actually stored in an SQlite database (I'm not 100% sure, though). The benefit of using SQlite's dynamic typing is that each value in the settings can be strong-typed (e.g. the "alerts.totalOpenTime" setting is an integer, while "app.update.channel" is a string) without having to have one separate column per type.

It's basically the same argument as for programming languages, in the end: why have dynamic typing in a programming language over static typing?